# What is the Akka DeathWatch?

Tags: akka, monitoring, actor

Straight from the Akka docs, section 2.5.5 ("*Reusing Actor Paths*"):

> When an actor is terminated, its reference will point to the dead letter mailbox, DeathWatch will publish its final transition and in general it is not expected to come back to life again (since the actor life cycle does not allow this).

I'm wondering what this `DeathWatch` is, and what role it plays with sending `Terminated` messages to other actors who are watching the (now) dead actor?

Comment: DeathWatch aka Lifecycle monitoring.

Comment: Thanks @johny but that comment is a wee bit cryptic and vague...did you write the Akka developer docs by any chance?!?